# Android - leaked objects without incoming references

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have a trouble with memory leak in HttpClient in Android. When I export hprof file and open it in Eclipse MAT, I can see, that there are two memory leak suspects.

1) 48 instances of "org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser", loaded by "" occupy 8 066 552 (61,52%) bytes. 
2) 12 instances of "org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer", loaded by "" occupy 2 098 480 (16,01%) bytes.

This is more than 3/4 of whole heap and more than 10MB of memory. Both is somewhere in HttpClient, both have no incoming references in MAT.

Do you have some ideas how to solve this? Ask me if you need more info.

Comment: I recommend following a short tutorial on using the MAT if you haven't done so already, such as http://sites.google.com/site/eclipsebiz/How-to-Find-Memory-Leaks. I am no expert myself on using the MAT, but from the few times I have successfully used it to resolve leaks, I didn't take much notice of the leak suspect pie charts it gives you on the front page. Instead I used the dominator_tree view, selecting 'list objects' or 'show objects by class' with ingoing/outgoing references. It takes some getting used to, but to get the hang of it you need to just dive in and click around.

Comment: Can you post the HPROF snapshot somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately there is allot of confidential data in HPROF file, including passwords and other stuff. Can I post some screenshots from MAT, or help you any other way?